# footer View issue in android

Tags: android

In my android app when the no of items in the list is small the footer sticks to end of the list like the one shown below.
[image]

but not to the end of screen.
Is there any way that i can stick it to the bottom of the screen.
I am using a seperate footer.xml and am calling it using Inflator service.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Relative layout and align it to bottom of parent:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<YourFooter
    android:id="@+id/SomethingSomething"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```